# Redirect URL after login - Angular

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I have an application on Angular 8 and after I login when in dev environment everything works just fine, the app is redirected to "/" (Here (1)) just like it should.

The problem is when I deploy it, after login the app goes to "url.com/login" and throw a 404 error. If I manually set to "url.com" everything works just fine.

This is the code on login Component:

```
    ngOnInit() {

    ...

       // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
       this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
       this.routeUsername = this.route.snapshot.params.username;

    }

    onSubmit() {
       this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
       .pipe(first())
       .subscribe(
          async data => {
             if (data.auth) {
                await this.commonSer.setLoginDetail(data);
                this.router.navigate(['/']); <-- Here (1)
                location.reload(); <-- Here (2)
             } else {
              
             ...

             }
          }, error => {

           ...

          });
    }
```

I also tried replacing "this.router.navigate(['/']);" for "this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);", but the result was exactly the same.

Another 2 awkwards situations are:

1. if I type any url on dev environment it works just fine, if I type a url on server, it throws a 404 error.
2. I had to add a location.reload() (Here (2)) in order to run any url. Otherwise even if I click on menu the url on browser changes but, nothing happens (both dev and production). And that´s something I don´t see in other people codes that often. I don´t know why I need it.

What am I missing here? What makes everything behaves the way it is?

UPDATE 1:
This is app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   ...
   //Login and Register Routes
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'login/:username', component: LoginComponent },
   { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
   { path: 'emailConfirmation', component: EmailConfirmationComponent },
   { path: 'emailConfirmation/:username', component: EmailConfirmationComponent },
   ...

   // Root
   { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   // Otherwise redirect to home
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

Comment: Where have you deployed ? Can you please show the server side code where you have handled the routing ?
It seems routing is taken over by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Route order

> The order of routes is important because the Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. List routes with a static path first, followed by an empty path route, which matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and the Router selects it only if no other routes match first.

move '{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },' before { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }, just after all other routes..

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and was a great tip. I just did it and I´m sure will prevent future problems. But unfortunately the previous problems are not solved by doing this.